# Missing Dependencies when generating executable using py2exe

Tags: python-2.7, dll, clr, py2exe, openpyxl

I have a problem in generating an executable from python and third party "DLL". I am using py2exe. At the end I getting a missing module error, but that module is defined in the DLL.

My Setup.py looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
import glob

setup(
    options = {'py2exe':{ "includes":["clr","openpyxl"]}},
    data_files=[('.', glob.glob('XLX2DBC.dll'))],
    windows = [{'script': "CANDBCGenerator.py"}],
    zipfile = None

)
```

What is the problem with this?

Comment: What is the traceback you are getting?

Comment: copying C:\Python27\DLLs\tcl85.dll -> C:\Users\t7245mh\Desktop\exp\files\dist
*** copy data files ***
copying XLX2DBC.dll -> C:\Users\t7245mh\Desktop\exp\files\dist\.
copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\run_w.exe -> C:\Users\t7245mh\Deskt
op\exp\files\dist\CANDBCGenerator.exe
The following modules appear to be missing
['DBVector_DBC', 'ElementC14N', 'Image', 'PIL', '_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata', 'l
xml.etree']

*** binary dependencies ***
Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included,
you may or may not need to distribute them.

Comment: that is the py2exe output.  The traceback when you run your .exe would be interesting to see.

Comment: When Run the Exe, got error window as "xxx.exe has stopped working" A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program. and "Close the program" button. I am not getting trace with this.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem, so i switched to pyinstaller. You can install it with pip install pyinstaller. Than you use: 
python pyinstaller.py --onefile your_main_file.py
the --onefile option will pack the dependencies into the EXE.
Here is a useful post on pyinstaller:
http://irwinkwan.com/2013/04/29/python-executables-pyinstaller-and-a-48-hour-game-design-compo/

Answer (score 0):

Stopped working error could be due to the MS runtime not being found.  The following wiki shows how to include them with py2exe.

http://wiki.wxpython.org/py2exe-python26

Python 2.7 uses version 9.0.30729.1 of the MS runtime, you should take them from your Python folder.

Comment: I got following error in trace:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CANDBCGenerator.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 98, in load_module
ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading clr.pyd

Comment: "includes" is for files, I suggest you use "packages" instead.